# QML can see my Q_GADGET but not Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Why can my `Q_GADGET` be read perfectly in QML (JS) but not my `Q_OBJECT`?

Running Qt 5.8.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm attempting to return a list (`QVariantMap`) of objects to QML.  I'm keeping it simple right now, no pointers, etc.. just copies of the objects.

```
struct Blob
{
   Q_GADGET

   Q_PROPERTY(QString uuid MEMBER uuid_ CONSTANT)
   Q_PROPERTY(QVector3D centroid MEMBER centroid_)
   // ...

   Blob() {};
   ~Blob() = default;
   Blob(const Blob& blob);
 };
 Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Blob)
```

There are a bunch of `QString` and `QVector3D` members on `Blob`.

In main.cpp, I also register the type:

```
qmlRegisterType<Blob>("matt", 1, 0, "Blob");
```

Then my JS code is able to read all the properties (for loop iterating over them) on the object without issue.

But if I use a `Q_OBJECT`

```
struct Blob : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   Q_PROPERTY(QString uuid MEMBER uuid_ CONSTANT)
   Q_PROPERTY(QVector3D centroid MEMBER centroid_)
   // ...

   explicit Blob(QObject parent = nullptr) : QObjecT(parent) {};
   ~Blob() = default;
   Blob(const Blob& blob);
 };
 Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Blob)
```

Then the JS receives an object where all the properies are the keys from the `QVariantMap`, but whose values are empty objects.

Note, before sending it to the JS, I convert it to a QVariant and back again just to confirm that that works, e.g.

```
Blob b;
qDebug() << "Created: " << b;
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(b);
qDebug() << "   Converted back = " << var.value<Blob>().toQString();
```

I'd prefer to use a `Q_OBJECT` such that I have slots/signals.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was seeing a difference between `Q_OBJECT` and `Q_GADGET` was that I was making copies of my object, which is allowed on a `Q_GADGET` (a *value*) object, but not on a `Q_OBJECT` (an *identity* object.)  See [identities instead of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433260/passing-q-gadget-as-signal-parameter-from-c-to-qml).

The solution is to always work on `Q_OBJECT`s with pointers.  This maintains their *identity*, and avoid copies.

Also, my original intent was to use a smart pointer, but the reasons why that is a bad approach are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411873/1861346).

The comment by @dtech also explained that `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is redundant on a `Q_OBJECT`.

Thus, my final declaration is:

*i.e.*

```
class Blob : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_PROPERTY(QString uuid MEMBER uuid_ CONSTANT)
  Q_PROPERTY(QVector3D centroid MEMBER centroid_)
  // ...

  explicit Blob(QObject parent = nullptr) : QObjecT(parent) {};
  ~Blob() = default;
  Blob(const Blob& blob);
};
```

With this, I can easily put a raw pointer to these objects in a `QVariantMap`, and they can be read on the QML/JS side.

Comment: You *always* work with `QObject` derived on pointer basis. Declaring a `QObject` derived as a meta type does not work, as it requires a copy-able object, and besides, all `QObject` derived get the MOC treatment, so they are by default meta types.

Comment: @dtech, I think I've now improved this answer using the advice from your comment (and the question comments that seem to have been deleted.)